# how to make calling activity(prepopup) wait to complete called activity(attendance) task?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

```
public void startAttendance(View view)
{
    Spinner sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tablepass);
    tbl_nm=sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(checkForEntries()!=0) {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ tbl_nm, null);
            if(c!=null) {
               if (c.moveToFirst())
                do {

                   String n1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                   String n2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Branch"));
                   Intent i = new Intent(this, Attendance.class);
                   Bundle b = new Bundle();
                   b.putString("n1", n1);
                   b.putString("n2", n2);
                   b.get("n1");
                   b.get("n2");
                   i.putExtras(b);
                   startActivity(i);
                   SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                   String attendance = sharedPref.getString("attendance", "default");
                   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                   cv.put("attendance", attendance);
                   db.insertOrThrow(tbl_nm, null, cv);
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }while(c.moveToNext());
               }
               }

}
```

****Attendance Activity****

```
public class Attendance extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    Bundle b=i.getExtras();
    String name=b.getString("n1");
    String branch=b.getString("n2");
    TextView tv5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView tv6=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    tv5.setText(name);
    tv6.setText(branch);
}

public void check(View v)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    switch (v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.button6:
            sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("attendance","present");
            editor.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("attendance","absent");
            editor.commit();
            break;


    }
    finish();
  }
}
```

Comment: prepopup is calling attendance activity iteratively and more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a wrong approach here, you are getting the data from local database and for every record you are calling another activity. That's why multiple instances of the Attendance activity are getting created.

You should first get all the record and store them in an arrayList, show a spinner with the data from this arrayList and when an item from the spinner is selected, then navigate to the Attendance Activity.
Ideally this should be the approach, because suppose there are 200 records, just imagine how many instances of Activity Attendance will be created,
Second thing if these many records have to manipulated and two activities are dependent on each other, I don't think user will wait for 200 records to popup each time on clicking a button.

Let me know if it works for you and what you think,
Mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others...